# Navigation - combine static_map with dynamic obstacle detection?

Tags: navigation, mapping, obstacle-avoidance, static-map, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

another pretty short question. For the `local planner` I'd like to combine a `static_map` (a pgm file) with obstacle data received from a laser scanner. Both information should be accumulated into a local costmap. Is it enough to set the `static_map` parameter of the local costmap to *true*? Or does that mean that no dynamic obstacles are detected and avoided by the local planner anymore? Or will it take more than that?

Reason is hat some of the static obstacles are out of the range of my scanner (i.e. below its horizontal detection arc). They are there, I know where they are, they stay there and won't move. Definition of static. All I need the laser scanner for are moving obstacles that I certainly cannot add to the static map.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170376/navigation---combine-static_map-with-dynamic-obstacle-detection?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually a needed feature for the navigation stack. The static map was originally only intended for use with the global costmap. Since the local map is usually in the odometry frame, if the robot was improperly localized, it would still be able to perform collision free local navigation.

However, as a result, I don't think you can use a static map well in the pre-hydro or post-hydro versions of navigation.

I've opened up [an issue on github](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/197)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-28**:
So I assume this cannot be solved by, let's say, next Sunday? Or is there a quick'n'dirty solution that might work but is just untested? And what do you mean with pre- and post-hydro? What about hydro itself? //edit: I suppose I could use the pgm file with an appropriate costmap layer module, right?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
For clarification, by post-hydro I meant hydro and the following versions.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-06-14**:
Alright, thanks.